# Google Places API for IOS does not set localized language

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, google-places-api

In my app I need user to pick a place using Google places. I call google place picker like so:

```
GMSPlacePicker * placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

GMSPlacesClient * placesClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient]; 

[placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {...}];
```

My problem is, that presented picking View has English language set instead of my localized language (Slovak). I have read that it is supposed to find localization by itself?

Comment: Any solution on this issue?

Comment: Not at all, if you find the solution, please write the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i did was to changing the default language in my app info.plist

```
Localization native development region to = "your language prefix goes here"
```

this changed my app localization and also changed the Google Place Picker to the the preferred language. 
my app also needs to be from left to right but my language is right to left so i also forced the app to "left to right" 
in my app delegate :

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceLeftToRight
```

take for consideration "semanticContentAttribute" supported only from ios 9 and above.

i hope this helps anyone struggling with this issue.